# First Questions Review Queue: Flagging a Question Does Not Advance the Actions or Move to Next Item

Tags: bug

In the new First Questions Review Queue, if I flag a question, say, as needing clarification, in my opinion the Actions box should have a button saying "I'm done" or the entire screen should advance to the next item. It's not at all clear what I should do next, as in my mind, I've already left feedback on that question. I notice that on Math.SE, the First Questions queue has the same behavior. Wondering if this is a SE-wide issue.

Comment: It might be a SE-wide issue. We (stats.SE mods and users) don't have much insight into how the software works, if anything is broken or bugged, etc. I think asking on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ will have more information, because SE employees monitor it.

Comment: Ah, I see it's already on their radar screen. Check out the answer **No way to correctly handle non-answers in First answers** on this thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release

Comment: Good find! Feel free to write your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is already on SE's radar. See this thread:

[Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release)

and check out the answer **No way to correctly handle non-answers in First Answers.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a new option now: Other action. It works similar to "I'm done."

[image]